# $\pi_1(\text{P}^2(\mathbb{R}))$ and multiplication by $2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, projective-space, fundamental-groups

I want to calculate the fundamental group of the real projective plane $\text{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ using SVK theorem.

To this end, I choose to model $\text{P}^2(\mathbb{R})\simeq D^2/{\sim} $ as the unit disk  $\{x:\|x\|\leq 1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ quotiented by identifying antipodal points lying on the boundary.

I take

- $A= \text{P}^2(\mathbb{R})-\{y\} $
- $B= \text{P}^2(\mathbb{R})-\partial$, where $\partial=\{x:\|x\|=1\}$
- $A\cap B$

which are all path-connected.

Now, fix a point $x_0 \in A\cap B.$

$A$ can be rectracted by deformation to $S^1$, so that $A \approx S^1$ and $\pi_1(S^1)\simeq \mathbb{Z}.$ The retraction $r_A:A \to S^1$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_1(A,x_0)\simeq\pi_1(S^1,r_A(x_0)) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ which is given by $[\lambda]_A \mapsto [r_A \circ \lambda]_{S^1}$ for every loop $\lambda$ in $A.$

If I call $c$ the loop corresponding to $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ under the isomorphism, I have the equality $\pi_1(S^1,r_A(x_0)) = \langle c | \emptyset \rangle $; the deformation, giving a path $h :t \mapsto h(t)=H(x_0,t)$ from $x_0$ to $r(x_0),$ also gives a presentation $\pi_1(A, x_0) = \langle hch^{-1},\emptyset \rangle $, where we can see now the generator as a loop with endpoints $x_0$ instead of $r(x_0).$

On the other hand, $B$ can be contracted to $\{x_0\},$ so $$\pi_1(B,x_0) \simeq \pi_1(\{x_0\},x_0)=\{x_0\} \simeq \{\text{id}\}= \langle \emptyset | \emptyset \rangle.$$

Finally, choosing another circle $S^1_{x_0}$ passing through $x_0$, I retract $A \cap B$ to it so that $$\pi_1(A\cap B, x_0)\simeq \pi_1(S^1_{x_0},x_0)= \langle \gamma| \emptyset \rangle.$$

The inclusion $A \cap B \subset B$ induces a morphism $b_*:\pi_1(A\cap B,x_0) \to \pi_1(B,x_0)$ which can only be the trivial map sending everything to the constant path at $x_0.$

Next, the inclusion $A \cap B \subset A$ induces a morphism of groups $a_*:\pi_1(A\cap B,x_0) \to \pi_1(A,x_0)$ given by $[\ell]_{A\cap B} \mapsto [\ell]_A$ for every loop $\ell$ in $A \cap B$ with endpoints $x_0.$

> I want to understand how to prove that the map $a_*$ as defined above has to be the multiplication by two $- \cdot 2: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2):

The morphism $a_*$ takes a loop $[\ell]_{A\cap B}=\gamma^n \in \pi_1(A\cap B,x_0)$ and sends it to the corresponding loop in $\pi_1(A,x_0),$ which, since the map is induced by the inclusion, is just $[\ell]_A$, (i.e. $\ell$ modulo homotopy in $A$).

Now we see $[\ell]_A$ inside $\pi_1(S^1,r_A(x_0))$ through the isomorphism $[\ell]_A \mapsto [r_A \circ \ell]_{S^1}$, and we have $[r_A \circ \ell]_{S^1}=c^{2n},$ because on the boundary antipodal points get identified, and so we go twice around the external circle as $[r_A \circ \ell (1/2)]=[-r(x_0)]=[r(x_0)]$ (here the equivalence classes are of points in $S^1$).

Pulling back to $\pi_1(A,x_0)$ we get $[\ell]_A=[hc^{2n}h^{-1}=(hch^{-1})^{2n}]_A$ and we conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Let $i:S^1\to D^2$ be the inclusion of the boundary and $p:D^2\to P^2(\mathbb R)$ the canonical projection.

In particular, $p\circ i: S^1\to P^2(\mathbb R)$  factors through $\partial$ (and thus through $A$, but the inclusion $\partial \to A$ is a homotopy equivalence); let's call $\alpha :S^1\to\partial$ the map we get.

We know that $\partial \cong S^1$, so what map is $\alpha_* : \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ ?

Well you have the following commutative diagram :

$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}S^1@>>> S^2 \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\partial @>>> P^2(\mathbb R)\end{CD}$

where the map $\partial \to P^2(\mathbb R)$ is the inclusion. If we identify $\partial \cong S^1$, the map $S^1\to S^1$ is simply $z\mapsto z^2$: that's an explicit computation you can make. Perhaps it's easier to actually define $\partial$ that way, and check that you get the same thing.

I think that might be the main point which wasn't clear to you, so if it still isn't, don't hesitate to tell me.

In particular, $\alpha_*=$ multiplication by $2$.

But also, $i$ is homotopic  to the inclusion of $S^1$ at a smaller circle in $D^2$, and therefore $p\circ i$ is homotopic to a homeomorphism $S^1\to S^1_{x_0}$.

So you have the following homotopy commutative diagram:

$\begin{CD} S^1 @>>> S^1_{x_0} @>\simeq>> A\cap B \\
@V=VV & & @VVV \\
 S^1 @>>> \partial @>\simeq>> A \end{CD}$

Taking $\pi_1$, since $\pi_1(S^1)\to \pi_1(S^1_{x_0})$ is an isomorphism and $\pi_1(S^1)\to \pi_1(\partial)$ is multiplication by $2$, we finally get that $\pi_1(A\cap B)\to \pi_1(A)$ is multiplication by $2$.

(technically you might have to worry about basepoints: there are at least two ways of dealing with this here: 1- note that all the fundamental groups involved are abelian, and so it doesn't change anything; or 2- do the same reasoning but with fundamental groupoids, and in the end patch things up)

Comment: Thank you. I was writing an answer myself and did not see yours.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is as follows, I think I will carry out a proof similar to your, so bear with me.

As you did, consider the projective plane $X$ and take a point $x_0$ in it. Then $U =  X\smallsetminus x_0$ deformation retracts into the sphere.

Take a small ball $V$ around $x_0$, so that $V\cap U$ also deformation retracts into a sphere.

Now for $V\cap U$, you will not have identified any boundary points, but in $U$, at the boundary sphere, you will identify them. This has the following consequence that you can form a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U\cap V @>{\pi}>> S^1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
U @>{\pi}>>S^1
\end{CD}$$

where the vertical map is of degree $2$. Essentially, it will send a generating loop in $U\cap V$ that winds *once* around the boundary to one that will wind *twice* around the boundary of $U$, since in there you will have identified antipodal points.

*Add.* If you want to be more precise, note that the generating loop for $U$ can be taken to be a loop in the unit disk that draws a half moon, going from $-1$ to $1$ in an almost straight line missing the origin and then through the arc.This makes it easy to see that the generating loop for $U\cap V$ will represent twice the previous loop in $U$.

Comment: I would prefer an answer that gives me the proof for my specific map; and also I would like a precise argument so that I can understand the details. At an intuitive level, I understand that the map picks a loop in the inner circle, and sends it to a loop in the boundary circle trough the path connecting x_0 and r(x_0), and then this new loop will be twice the generator because of the equivalence relation identifying antipodal points. But what I’m trying to do is prove this in a clean way without too much handwaving.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ggeolier The proper way to go, then, is as follows: projective space is the quotient of $S^2$ by the action of $\mathbb Z/2$ sending $z\to -z$. Then $\pi : S^2\to \mathbb RP^2$ is a covering projection with transformation group $\mathbb Z/2$ and hence $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^2) = \mathbb Z/2$. That is, you can proceed much like the computation of $\pi_1(S^1)$ using $\pi : \mathbb R\to S^1$.

Comment: @ggeolier (Note that what I wrote is not hand wavy. You can write down the parametrizations of the curves I describe and see exactly what the map from the sphere to itself is. It is a sketch, though.)

Comment: Be careful: $D^2\to \mathbb RP^2$ is not a covering, it's $S^2\to \mathbb RP^2$ that is. Though the rest of the argument remains unchanged of course

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I don't know why you talk about parametrizations. You can parametrize as you want but the map will be just an inclusion from the big sphere to the little sphere inside, independently of the parametrization, which doesn't tell you anything about the map induced on the fundamental groups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments which were still useful. I managed to write  the answer I wanted myself.

Comment: @Maxime Fixed that. :)